# How to sort Array of tuples (String,String,int)

Tags: swift

I have an array of tuples. I want to sort the list by first element of tuples.

Example:

```
var names = [("C","MTS",4),("A","MTS",3),("M","SMTS",1),("N","LEAD",5)];
```

i want to sort them in the below order by first element of tuples

```
[("A","MTS",3),("C","MTS",4),("M","SMTS",1),("N","LEAD",5)];
```

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var names = [("C","MTS",4),("A","MTS",3),("M","SMTS",1),("N","LEAD",5)]
names.sortInPlace{ $0.0 < $1.0 }

// You can use this if it more clearly:
// names.sortInPlace { (name1: (String, String, Int), name2: (String, String, Int)) -> Bool in
       // return name1.0 < name2.0
//}

print(names)
//[("A", "MTS", 3), ("C", "MTS", 4), ("M", "SMTS", 1), ("N", "LEAD", 5)]
```

Comment: It didn't work. Throwing an error :"Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two ('String','String,Int) operands.

Comment: Maybe you typed wrong, it should be `(String, String, Int)` not `('String','String,Int)`. I have tried and it worked for me.

Comment: This one worked:    names.sortInPlace { (name1: (String, String, Int), name2: (String, String, Int)) -> Bool in
            return name1.0 < name2.0
        };